# How to use streams to return boolean value depending of enum type - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, java-stream

I have a method with which I would like to check if, in my model, enum of some type exists.
If it exists I want to return `true` an if not I would like to return `false` with error message.

I have model that looks like this:

```
@Data
public class DataResponse {

    public final String userId;
    public final List<Model> modelList;

}
```

**Model.java**

```
@Data
public class Model {
    public final String modelId;
    public final ModelType type;
    public final ModelStatus status;
}
```

**ModelType.java**

```
public enum ModelType {
    Fast,
    Slow;
}
```

**ModelStatus.java**

```
public enum ModelStatus {
    CREATED,
    FAILED
}
```

Now I would like to check using strems if my model contains type `"Fast"` and if contains status `"CREATED"` if yes return `true` if not return `false` with error message.

So far I have this:

```
public Boolean isModelFastAndSuccess(String modelId){
    Optional<DataResponse> modelList = dataService.getModelStatus(modelId);
    userProofList.stream().map(ml -> ml.modelList)
            .map(models -> {
                if() 
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I am not sure how to finish it.
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `return userProofList.stream().any/all/noneMatch(/* some predicate */);`?

Comment: Can you write it maybe as code example for my example?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are going to return _false with error message_?

Comment: True, guess error message would be enough

Comment: Then how the method `isModelFastAndSuccess` is supposed to return _something_ which is a boolean and a String message at the same time?  Also, it is not clear whether the response field `modelList` has to contain _all_ models `Fast` and `Created` or just _any_?

Comment: Yes, that would work as well

Answer (score 0):

The approach to implementation of `isModelFastAndSuccess` could be as follows assuming that `dataService::getModelStatus` returns `Optional<DataResponse>`:

```java
public Boolean areAllModelsFastAndSuccess(String modelId) {
    return dataService.getModelStatus(modelId) // Optional<DataResponse>
        .map(DataResponse::getModelList) // Optional<List<Model>>
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) // List<Model>
        .stream() // Stream<Model>
        .allMatch(model -> model.getType() == ModelType.Fast 
                        && model.getStatus() == ModelStatus.CREATED
        );
}
```

Also, a method may be implemented to return `true` if there is at least one `Fast / Created` model:

```java
public Boolean isAnyModelFastAndSuccess(String modelId) {
    return dataService.getModelStatus(modelId) // Optional<DataResponse>
        .map(DataResponse::getModelList) // Optional<List<Model>>
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) // List<Model>
        .stream() // Stream<Model>
        .anyMatch(model -> model.getType() == ModelType.Fast 
                        && model.getStatus() == ModelStatus.CREATED
        );
}
```